# Javascript end to 2 decimals not working

Tags: javascript, input, tofixed

i'm trying to set an output value from 2 fields to 2 decimals.
i've tried doing this with: `.toFixed(2)` but it didn't work for me. I tried doing this:

```
calculate = function () {
      var total = document.getElementById('totaal').value;
      var btw = document.getElementById('percentage').value;
      document.getElementById('btw').value = parseInt(total.toFixed(2)) * parseInt(btw.toFixed(2)) / 100;
  }
```

If the field ends on a number with 2 decimals (for example: 3,45) it is working correctly.
But if it ends with a 0, it does not show the 0.

I think this shoudn't be this mutch of a deal but i'm just trying for half a day now...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `parseInt()` you then get the numbers after the decimal points removed, try doing this :

```
document.getElementById('btw').value = (parseFloat(total) * parseFloat(btw) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

`parseFloat` converts the string (and it's necessary because input values are string) in the input to a float, then divide by 100 and call `.toFixed(2)` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert a string to number by using an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```
document.getElementById('btw').value = (+total * +btw / 100).toFixed(2);
```

If you use `parseInt`, you loose precision, which you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFloat`  to achieve this

```js
var total =65633;
var btw  = 12;

console.log(parseFloat((total* btw)/100).toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is that you're running `toFixed()` on strings, and `toFixed()` only works on numbers.

You could however, do this:

```
document.getElementById('btw').value = 
        (parseInt(total) * parseInt(btw) / 100).toFixed(2)
```

This takes the two numbers and does all the math. It then converts it to a string with two trailing decimals

See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6vtrjmax/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `toFixed` on the entire operation i.e. `document.getElementById("btw").value = (parseInt(total) * parseInt(btw) / 100).toFixed(2);`

Try running the snippet below:

```js
calculate = function() {
  var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
  var btw = document.getElementById("percentage").value;
  if (total && btw) {
    document.getElementById("btw").value = 
      (parseInt(total) * parseInt(btw) / 100).toFixed(2);
  }
};
```

```html
<input onchange="calculate()" placeholder='total' type="decimal" id="total">
<input onchange="calculate()" placeholder='percentage' type="decimal" id="percentage">
<input type="decimal" placeholder='result' id="btw">
```